# MySQL trigger after update on the same table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a MySQL trigger using the  `BEFORE INSERT ON table` that calculates a value and updates the same table after a user inserts values in specific columns. This works as expected. But a user makes a mistake in their entry and fixes their error and I want to write a trigger that will update the calculated value after the error has been fixed. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE?

Comment: Add a BEFORE or AFTER UPDATE trigger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `BEFORE UPDATE ON table` trigger has access to the existing values in the row as well as newly supplied values, and can set the value of any column in the table, based on whatever conditions and expressions we want.

For example, it's possible to test whether the value of one or more columns of concern has been modified, and then set some other column to some expression.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER my_before_update_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NOT ((NEW.col1 <=> OLD.col1) AND (NEW.col2 <=> OLD.col2)) THEN
      SET NEW.col3 = NEW.col1 * NEW.col2 ;
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, following your example, what am I doing wrong? It complains about a syntax error!
    `CREATE TRIGGER my_before_update_trigger 
     BEFORE UPDATE ON TmapSlideData
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
        IF NOT ((NEW.MappedReads <=> OLD.MappedReads) AND (NEW.FOV <=> OLD.FOV))
            SET NEW.MappedReadsPerFOV=NEW.MappedReads/NEW.FOV;
        END IF;
     END$$`

Comment: My example is missing a `THEN` keyword. And that `$$` is a sample delimiter, you need a matching (preceding) `DELIMITER $$` statement. And you probably want to consider a trigger naming convention that includes the name of the table in the trigger name. (That's not a MySQL requirement, but it can be a handy convention in larger schemas, with lots of tables and lots of triggers.) Another thing to consider is whether it's actually necessary to store that derived column. That value could be returned by including the relevant expression in the SELECT list of a query.